# Backbone+undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have an app with several models. They load up fine and I can see them in the Backbone inspector. `App.Models.<model name>`.

I've added a model to this app by extending the Model as per :

```
App.Models.Invitation = Backbone.Model.extend({

};
```

The model does not show up in the app and when I attempt to create a 'new' one I get this error :

> undefined is not a function.

I'm positive I'm missing something however, can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: how are you instantiating the new model?

Comment: can you add the line of code that generate that error ?

Comment: don't forget your close bracket

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
var Invitation = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Comment: ha thanks but that was just a typo. I'm instantiating it properly. It's basically an issue (I think) where the precompiler isn't generating the .js file for the model.

Comment: the offending line is: var invite = new App.Models.Invitation();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. Turns out there was a client_javascript_manifest.js file that needed a reference to my model. Once that happened all fell into place. Thanks again.